# localization of django template

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, localization

I am trying to localize the date field in django template. Created and Completed date format is hardcoded as 'M d, Y'.

```
<td class="medium-2 columns">{{ report.created|date:'M d, Y' }}</td>
<td class="medium-2 columns">{{ report.completed|date:'M d, Y' }}</td>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, The Created and Completed date format should correspond to the current language. For example,

> German (DE): 17. Jan 2017
>
> English (EN): Jan 17, 2017
>
> Spanish (ES): 17 ene de 2017 (17 enero de 2017)

I have in my settings.py file

> LANGUAGES = (
>
> ```
> ('en', _('English')),
> ('fr', _('French')),
> ('it', _('Italian')),
> ('es', _('Spanish')),
> ('de', _('German')),
> ('ja', _('Japanese')),
> ```
>
> )
>
> USE_L10N = True

what is the best way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{ value|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#date